# How to add focus on label css style

Tags: html, css, focus

I'm trying to make an element that looks like a button with a radio button inside of it. When the user selects an option I would like to create an active state on the button with the background #CCC.

Here is the relevant code.

```css
.butOption {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.butOption:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.butOption input {
  margin: 20px;
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<label class="butOption">
  <div class="radioBut">
    <input type="radio" name="item" value="" checked />
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</label>
<label class="butOption">
  <div class="radioBut">
    <input type="radio" name="item" value="" checked />
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</label>
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: when clicked on the label i want it to stay with the background color #ccc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using javascript. I still haven't been able to find a way to do this with only CSS and HTML.

([Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/nydhj27t/6/))

Using javascript you basically capture the click event then remove the class `active` from the currently active option, then add the `active` class to the clicked item's class definition

JAVASCRIPT

```
document.getElementById("button1").onclick = function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("active")[0].className = 'butOption';
    this.className += ' active';
};
document.getElementById("button2").onclick = function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("active")[0].className = 'butOption';
    this.className += ' active';
};
```

CSS

```
.active {
    background: #CCC;
}
```

Comment: thanks but I would still want to see if someone can accomplish it in just CSS, but thank you.